# Del operator in spherical coordinates?

Tags: calculus, analysis, differential-geometry

I am trying to find the formulae for Del operators in n-dimensional spherical coordinates.
For 3D, I found them here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates

Could you recommend any references for it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The Wikipedia article seems to cover most of it already. Or are you looking for derivations of the formulae?

Comment: I am looking for the formulae in general n-dimensional sphererical coordinates. That article only shows 3 dimensional case.

Comment: Do you know how to parametrize $S^n$?